# Algorithm to maximize variance within classes in two dimensions under constraint

Tags: sampling, algorithms, constraint

I am working on a problem that has two dimensions, A and B.  Within the two dimensions, there are 6,140 unique points.  Each point has a cost associated with it.  I have a total cost that I cannot exceed.

I want to optimally sample N of the points such that:

1. I maximize the variance in A,
2. I maximize the variance in B,
3. I do not exceed my total cost limit

Basically, I want to get the most discrete values of A and the most discrete values of B so that my sample can come as close as possible to representing all of the points in the set.  Are there any algorithms that would lead me to this solution?

**Edit:** The number of points N can vary.  Ideally, you could have a lot of low cost points or a few number of high cost points.  The figure below shows the set of points from which to sample.

[image: Plot of A vs. B]

Comment: What does the image represent?  The set of points that can be sampled?

Comment: Is $N$ fixed, or can it vary?

Comment: Do you really want to maximize the variance?

Comment: I want to get the get the most representative sample in two dimensions.  Seems like variance would be a good start, but if you have another method I'm not exactly sure where to go on this.